# Creating multiple Redis databases in Redis Enterprise

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

Our application has 1000+ tenants and we'd like to employ Redis Enterprise to dedicate a database to each of the tenants. Creating each tenant database using Redis Enterprise's admin portal is a tedious task for 1000+ tenants. What's the best way to create the databases in a batch? Any scripts or API to use to achieve this goal?

Comment: Are you using Redis Enterprise Cloud or Software?

Comment: Software which will be hosted on Azure Cloud. I assume that your answer below still applies, right? @stockhomux

Comment: Yes. As long as you are on Redis Software, it should be the same. The managed cloud product is quite different though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redis Enterprise REST API is pretty extensive. To create a DB just `POST Application-json` with appropriate auth to `https://<cluster_fqdn>:9443/v1/bdbs`

```
    "name": "testdb1",
    "type": "redis",
    "replication": true,
    "memory_size": 100000000
}
```

Therefore you can bulk create DBs. The API has a lot of other useful endpoints at `/v1/cluster`, `/v1/nodes`, `/v1/users` to name a few.

Just a note, you probably want to touch base with your contact at Redis Labs before doing this in production, there might be other details on your specific deployment. They can also point you in the right direction for how to better use the REST API which is supported but not fully documented publicly.